# Merging google account and gsuite/google apps account

Tags: android, google-apps, google-account, google-workspace

I use email in my custom domain -> me@myself.com, email hosting is outside google. I used this email to create new google account, which I later used on my android phone.

Now, what will happen if I move email hosting for myself.com to google (gsuite or legacy google apps), will it merge with my 'normal' google account and I still have access to purchased apps etc.?

Another scenario: I delete my 'normal' google account and register for email hosting and use this account on my phone. What will happen if I close that hosting later? Does my account 'revert' to standard one with the same email? Do I still have access to purchased apps etc.?

Answer (score 0):

When you move your domain to G Suite and create an account with the same name like you already have, then your first account becomes conflicting account.

> To resolve this conflict in account names, the data in the personal Google Account will need to be re-associated with a different account name. The next time you sign in to your conflicting account, you will be asked to change the name you use to sign in, in order to continue accessing the data in your conflicting account.

Read more here: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/188609